# Scaling images proportional in CSS (if possible, without JS!)

Tags: html, image, css

I want to proportionally scale images using CSS.

The image should be shown in the full container size, it should become larger **or** smaller (depending on the container size). I also want to display it in the middle.

Edit: I already tried `min-width: 100%;` and `max-width: 100%;`. That only works in one direction. When using `min-width: 100%; max-height: auto;` the main problem is solved but the picture is sometimes displayed too large (that means that the user has to scroll). I want it to be fully displayed, when this is not possible, the browser shall increase the margins.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe a jsfiddle be good to understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img{
    max-width: 100%; /* If not scaling above native size */
}
```

**OR**

```
img{
    width: 100%; /* Change this using media queries */
}
```

**OR**

```
background-size
```

To display it in the centre of a container, give the container a rule of `text-align: center;` images are by default inline elements so they behave like text and will be positioned in the  centre of the container.

Comment: When typing "max-width: 100%;" this only works in one direction (it's only becoming smaller), but when I increase the percentage it looses its effect.

Comment: If its being scaled why don't you use media queries to control the width of the image?

The alternative if you don't want to do the above is to use a background image. You could use background-size to then control how it scales up or down.